# How to read image sequence and how to acess individual pixels in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to read a sequence of gray scale images of size 256*256 from memory and store in a array. Later I want to access individual pixels of each image from array. How can i do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "read images ... from memory". Where would these images come from? In case you want to read FROM a file INTO memory, you would use the function imread, type `doc imread` at the MATLAB prompt to learn about it. If you want to load an image sequence, you probably have to call imread once for each image.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
NumImages = 20;

% reading
for Ind = 1:NumImages
    % replace by your read image function
    ImgArray(:, :, Ind) = rand(256, 256);
end

% accessing the pixel in place (1, 2) of the 3rd img in array
SinglePixel = ImgArray(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: As an alternative, one may store the different images in a cell array: `ImgArray{Ind} = rand(256, 256);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have 6 256x256 images named by 'IM1.jpg' to 'IM6.jpg', in the folder 'C:\ImagesSeq\'. Now you want to read these into Matlab.

```
IMArray=zeros(256,256,6); % preallocate the memonry for your image array 

for i=1:6 % you can replace 6 by any number you need
    Filename=sprintf('C:/ImagesSeq/IM%d.jpg',i);
    IMArray(:,:,i)=imread(Filename);
end

% you can now accessing the pixel as last answer shows by indexing the Image array
SinglePixel = IMArray(1, 2, 3);
```

I hope this is what you mean....:)